# PauliMatrix tensor product

Tags: list-manipulation

My Pauli matrices are:

```
x = PauliMatrix[1];
y = PauliMatrix[2];
z = PauliMatrix[3];
one = PauliMatrix[0];
a1=(m - tx) TensorProduct[z, one, z]
a2=-I*A*TensorProduct[x, z, one]
```

As shown above I try to calculate Pauli matrix tensor product, I hope the dimensions of both `a1` and `a2` are 8*8 and its result is correct. The truth is `a1` and `a2` have a lots of `{}`.

Comment: Use KroneckerProduct[x,z,one].

Comment: Please allow me to shamelessly promote my book [**Using Mathematica for Quantum Mechanics: _A Student’s Manual_**](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.7050.pdf), where this is explained in chapter 2 (particularly section 2.4) and then applied to Pauli matrix products in chapter 3.